# Can't Access Spring Boot API in docker container

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to run my application in a docker container on my machine but am having issues hitting any of my endpoints. (everything works fine when i run it locally)

```
#DOCKERFILE 
FROM tomcat:latest

RUN mkdir  -p /app/fleet-service
WORKDIR /app/fleet-service

COPY /target/fleet-view-1.0.0.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/fleet-view-1.0.0.war

EXPOSE 8080
```

The image builds fine and i am running it with the following cmd:

```
docker run --rm -p 8080:8080 <imagename>
```

I am confused because the application deploys successfully as i can see the logs in my docker terminal. There are no errors and the database connection is valid. However, when i go to:

```
<docker-machine-ip>:8080 
-> i get the tomcat website saying that tomcat is running

<docker-machine-ip>:8080/api/vehicles/ 
-> should return data as it does when i run it locally but instead i get a '404 Not Found'.
```

I think i am very close but i don't know where to go from here. There is no application context to take into consideration. Also application is in fact running on 8080.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated and if you need more information please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: have you checked the catalina.out and saw that the .war was correctly deployed? It's typical that tomcat starts anyway, despite the success or not of the deployment

Comment: @Robert - Yes the application is deployed. I get the same logging as i do when i run it locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple, but easily overlooked - I had to add the application context.

docker-machine-ip:8080/fleet-view-1.0.0/api/vehicles

works just fine.